C program to sum up total mem usage of any proc
I'm trying to get the most accurate number I can for the total amount of memory being utilized by any process. My approach is to print all of the lines of /proc/PID/maps, find the difference of the two mem addresses supplied and add that number to a totalMem variable. As an example, here's one line from the /proc/PID/maps file:
7f00a05c9000-7f00a05cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

I have some C code (shown below) to get the difference and add it to the total.
The proc I'm working with is firefox, and the problem is, the total mem comes out to:
13050814464 bytes

which even I know isn't correct.
My C code to handle the mem address difference is:
while ( (read = getline(&line, &len, fd_MapsFile) != -1) ) {
    char *space = strchr(line, ' ');

    if (space == NULL) {
        printf("invalid input string\n");
    }

    size_t len = space - line;

    char address[50];

    strncpy(address, line, len);
    address[len] = '\0';

    char address1[20];
    char address2[20];

    char *hyphen = strchr(address, '-');

    if (hyphen == NULL ) {
        printf("no hyphen found");
    }

    size_t address1len = hyphen - address;
    strncpy(address1, address, address1len);
    address1[address1len] = '\0';

    size_t address2len = strlen(address) - address1len - 1;
    strncpy(address2, hyphen+1, address2len);
    address2[address2len] = '\0';

    unsigned long addr1 = strtoul(address1, NULL, 16);
    unsigned long addr2 = strtoul(address2, NULL, 16);
    unsigned long difference = addr2 - addr1;

    printf("difference: %lu\n", difference);

    totalMem = totalMem + difference;
}

And while I'm not too confident in my C, I'm thinking it's more of a source problem.
Some of my conclusions as to why the number is so big:
The kernel might be rounding the mem addresses up to accomadate page size, which makes sense as my page size is 4kb and the majority of my mem address differences are 4kb. This could mean the actually mem being used could be smaller.
I'm not accounting for deleted segments of memory which are displayed in the /proc/PID/maps file like so:
7f009120f000-7f0091210000 rw-s 00000000 00:01 2096                       /memfd:mozilla-ipc (deleted)

I'm assuming I should subtract these from the total
If anyone has any other ideas as to how to get the most accurate reading for total mem usage of a proc (other than some builtin), please share!

How does the memory consumption that you calculate compare to what you see in top and other similar tools?

You could also use program that allocates a big chunk of memory and does some stuff in that area. That what you know approximately what the correct result should be if you measure its memory consumption.

@TedLyngmo top is showing my total mem usage is 6bg, not possible for firefox to utilize 13, top is the util I'll be using to check my findings (firefox mem% / total mem usage)

Ok, but if you write a program (or use memhog) to allocate a fixed known size, you'll have an easier time to verify your memory measuring program.

Just make sure that the whole allocated memory area is used in a way that can't be optimized away when the program is executed so that the OS doesn't "cheat" :)

I'd still be looking at the /proc/PID/maps file however and I'm starting to think this isn't the right approach

You want to look at:
/proc/PID/status

In that, the VmSize: is what you want. There are other Vm*: fields that may also be of interest, but VmSize: is the total for all.
This value corresponds to the VSZ field that ps alx reports for the given PID
Although you may want to read this yourself in code, here's a quick example ...
On my system, I ran:
ps alx | egrep 'VSZ|firefox' | head -2
egrep "^Pid:|VmSize:" /proc/`pgrep firefox`/status

The output:
F   UID     PID    PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 2784648       1  20   0 13147128 845044 x64_sy Sl tty1     15:36 /hdx/local/firefox/firefox-bin https://www.thunderbird.net/
Pid:    2784648
VmSize: 13147128 kB

